# Combining projects into a single JAR

Tags: jar, merge, gradle

I'm trying to combine 4 projects into one JAR like this

```
jar {
    from {
        project(":p1").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
        project(":p2").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
        project(":p3").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    }
}
```

It sort of works, there are parts from each three projects there, but incomplete. Whenever there's a common directory like `p1/mypackage` and `p2/mypackage`, Gradle fails to merge them and takes (I think) the last one. So instead of combining

```
p1
  mypackage
    MyFirst.class
p2
  mypackage
    MySecond.class
```

into

```
mypackage
    MyFirst.class
    MySecond.class
```

I get only one class. There's no warning. Is this expected or a bug (I hope so)? Can I avoid it somehow?

---

As stated in the answer, I was doing all wrong. With

```
jar {
    from {[
        project(":p1").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
        project(":p2").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
        project(":p3").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    ]}
}
```

it seems to work.

---

But this is better:

```
jar {
    from {[":p1", ":p2", ":p3"].collect {project(it).sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the return value of the closure matters, so the first two lines are no-ops. Also, the necessary task dependencies need to be established. Try:

```
jar {
    from { subprojects.sourceSets.main.output }
}
```

(`SourceSetOutput` is `Buildable`, which means that Gradle can infer the task dependencies automatically.)

Comment: Really? Then I've been doing it all wrong. But I don't want all the `subprojects`, only three of them. I could do some filtering or joining of the three sets, but could you kindly show me how? I'm pretty clueless here as you can see.